# Does a smart pointer support invoking a member function via a pointer?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>

class BASE
{
public:
    int fun1(int i){return i * 1;}
};

int main(){
    int (BASE::*pf2)(int);
    boost::shared_ptr<BASE> pB = boost::make_shared<BASE>();
    pf2 = &BASE::fun1;
    std::cout << (pB->*pf2)(3) << std::endl; // compile wrong: error: no match for 'operator->*' in 'pB ->* pf2'|
}
```

Does this mean the Boost library do not implement '->*' operator to support the use it to invoke member function pointer?

Comment: Class `BASE` has no member `pf2` defined. Did you mean `fun2`?

Comment: You should show the definition of `pf2` -- I assume it is a pointer to a  member function of `BASE`?

Answer (score 4):

You should write:

```
std::cout << ((*pB).*pf2)(3) << std::endl;
```

As I checked, Boost does not define operator `->*` for any of the pointers, although it is possible (see C++ standard, sections 5.5 and 13.5).

Also, the C++11 standard does not define this operator for C++11 smart pointers.

Comment: He uses `pf2`, which (according to topic) is a pointer to member function. So - you're wrong.

Comment: @Griwes Code supplied by OP was ambiguous. I fixed my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I would guess that you should do it this way:

```
std::cout << ((*pB).*pf2)(3) << std::endl;
```

although it's not tested.